# Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, module

I have begun learning to program (in general, and in Python), and I am trying to import a module. I have installed it (using pip install --user requests) and the folder appears in my file explorer. When I try to import requests now inside IDLE, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I have tried adding the folder to the PATH environment variable, although I am not sure I understand what this means, but it did not work. What can I do?

Comment: What does "pip freeze" say? Is the requests module there?

Comment: Yes, pip freeze finds requests

Comment: then close the IDLE and type "python -m idlelib" .. new IDLE will open and then try to import

Comment: wonderful, thank you so much! if you put this as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "pip freeze" lists the module, then one option will be to close the idle and type the following at the command prompt/terminal.

```py
python -m idlelib
```

New IDLE will start and it should be possible to import the module.

Answer (score 2):

That means that the installation you made was not done properly, so when you type in `requests` to get the module in your script it cannot find it.

Just reinstall it properly with (if the prompt for the python version you want to use is simply `python`):

```py
python -m pip install requests
```

---

EDIT:

Adding to this, based on the comment of @AST :

Indeed, if you get `Requirement already satisfied` when using the above command, you can first delete `requests` with the following command, and *then* try the installation command.

```py
pip uninstall requests
```

Comment: Then it says: Requirement already satisfied, and cites the path where requests is stored. It doesn't install it again.

Comment: @user242318 You can use `pip uninstall requests` and then execute the upper code.